# php Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, json, warnings

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I really don't understand and don't find why :(

I have warning at this line

```
foreach($formResponse as $obj){
    $formResponse = array();
    $formResponse = '[
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_Amount", "value": '.$data['Amount'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_Order", "value": '.$data['Id'].'}, 
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode", "value": '.$data['Fuc'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_Terminal", "value": '.$data['Terminal'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_TransactionType", "value": '.$data['Trans'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_Titular", "value": '.$data['Titular'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_MerchantName", "value": '.$data['Nombre'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_MerchantData", "value": '.sha1($data['Notify_url']).'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL", "value": '.$data['Notify_url'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_ProductDescription", "value": '.$data['Productos'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_UrlOK", "value": '.$data['Notify_url'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_UrlKO", "value": '.$data['Notify_url'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_MerchantSignature", "value": '.$data['Firmafinal'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_ConsumerLanguage", "value": '.$data['Idiomas'].'},
        {"name": "Ds_Merchant_PayMethods", "value": '.$data['Tipopago'].'}
    ]';             

    $formResult = "<form action=". $data['action']." method='post'>'";

    foreach($formResponse as $obj){
        $inputName = $obj -> name; 
        $inputValue = $obj -> value; 

        $formResult .= "<input type='hidden' name='". $inputName ."' value='". $inputValue ."'></input>";
    }
```

Comment: json_decode($formResponse);

Comment: You've created `$formResponse` as a JSON string when you need it as a PHP array.

Comment: Your $formResponse isn't an array anymore ...

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$formResponse=json_decode($formResponse);
```

Before the start of foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decode the json data before using foreach loop because it only accept arrays and objects    you have to use `$formResponse=json_decode($formResponse, true);`